# Hide menubar and dock after fullscreen video in WebView

Tags: cocoa, webview, fullscreen, menubar, dock

I have a cocoa application which is a fullscreen webbrowser using WebView.
Initially the menubar and dock are hidden, and cannot be accessed, which is how I want it, but after a fullscreen window such as a video is displayed, the menubar and dock reappear and stay there.

Any idea how to prevent them from reappearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, got it. SetSystemUIMode is my friend. I was just searching for the wrong thing on google, that's why I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the video player hid the already hidden menubar & dock when it went full screen. Then when it finished, it showed them again.

You'll probably have to hide them again yourself after the video is done..

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd like to do, but how do I do that?

Comment: Ah, got it. SetSystemUIMode is my friend. I was just searching for the wrong thing on google, that's why I didn't see it.